# AcceptOnceFileListFilter is overriding SimplePatternFileListFilter in Spring Integration JAVA DSL

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have following code:

```
return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("data"))
                        .filter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"))
                        .filter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>()),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay("1000"))
                                .id("fileInboundChannelAdapter"))
                .split(new FileSplitter())
                .<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, m -> m.channelMapping(String.class, "tranform.input")).get();
```

My **SimplePatternFileListFilter** is not working, but if I remove **AcceptOnceFileListFilter**, it works fine.

Is it intended, that only one FileListerFilter can be passed? If yes, any workaround possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. Since we don't know how you are going to combine them and what is the order, therefore only one `.filter()` can be configured. However at the same time there is a `CompositeFileListFilter` and `ChainFileListFilter` for your choice to compose a set of filters. And the order there matters already.

All the hard work underneath is delegated to the `FileListFilterFactoryBean` and the composition and mutually exclusivity is dictated by that one.

I guess we need to provide more cleaner JavaDocs on the matter. Feel free to raise a JIRA and we will fix it soon.

Comment: Thanks @artem-bilan, will try CompositeFileListFilter and ChainFileListFilter then..